# Find the number $n^{2}$ from the number $n^{n^{n^{2}}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> Find the number $n^{2}$ from the number $\large n^{n^{n^{2}}}$

Any help? I tried with $\log$ but I got nothing.

Comment: If you do $\log\left(n^{n^{n^2}}\right)$, you get $n^{n^2}\log(n)$. But $n^2$ is in the exponent again. What do you do to get something out of the exponent?

Comment: Is $n$ guaranteed to be a positive integer?

Comment: I think so.,,,,,

Comment: If someone hands you an actual number, written out, then $n$ can only be 0, 1, or 2; $3^{3^{3^2}}$ already has over 9000 decimal digits, and $4^{4^{4^2}}$ has billions. Even scientific notation will fail soon after that, because the exponent will have too many digits to write down.

Comment: Is there anyone can solve this for me guys??

Comment: Well, it should be clear that $n^{n^{n^2}}$ is a strictly monotonic increasing function on $(0,\infty)$ (since it is a composition of strictly increasing functions), implying that an inverse exists.  It is not likely to be a currently defined mathematical function however due to its extremely limited use.  Things get strange if you allow $n$ to be negative however.  Certainly, [even wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+of+y%3Dx^%28x^%28x^2%29%29) doesn't know what to call the inverse.

Comment: Please, what is the source of this problem?

Comment: I say, PLEASE, WHAT IS THE SOURCE OF THIS PROBLEM?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have no idea

Comment: You don't know where you saw the problem?

Comment: @GerryMyerson someone give it to me.

Answer (score 1):

A slight extension of the idea to take logs suggested by OP and @CameronWilliams can
be used to get an inelegant partial solution based on the obvious
computations. While it does go farther than I thought possible
from the Comment by @EricTressler, one can hope that a general
solution can be found in closed form that does not depend on
computation.

For $n = 2, \dots 25,\;$ let $q = n^2,\; h = n^{n^q}$ and
$$c = \lfloor \log_{10}(\log_{10}(h))\rfloor
= \lfloor q \log_{10}(n) + \log_{10}(\log_{10}(n))\rfloor.$$
Use $c$ in the following table to find $n$ and $q.\;$ (If $h = 1,$
then $n = n^2 = 1.$)

```
      n   q   c
      ---------
      2   4   0
      3   9   3
      4  16   9
      5  25  17
      6  36  27
      7  49  41
      8  64  57
      9  81  77
     10 100 100
     11 121 126
     12 144 155
     13 169 188
     14 196 224
     15 225 264
     16 256 308
     17 289 355
     18 324 406
     19 361 461
     20 400 520
     21 441 583
     22 484 649
     23 529 720
     24 576 795
     25 625 873
```

With suitable software this table might be extended to somewhat
larger values of $n,$ but this table illustrates the idea.
Maybe it will give someone a clue towards a closed form solution.